# Pain on Inside of Elbow after light impact

Tags: injury, football, elbows

I play Football, and while I was going to hit the ball, I bumped the receiver with my elbow while jumping up and reaching for the ball. The next play I was surprised that my elbow hurt quite badly whenever any pressure was put on it. After trying out a few things I have noticed that my elbow doesn't hurt at all when pulling, just when pushing, but even tiny amounts hurt (even putting on a seat belt).

Does anyone have any ideas on what happened? I would really like to know whether it is safe to continuing practice or if I have to take a day or two off. If the only problem is pain, I can deal with that, but if I will make it worse, than I would love to know.

Comment: Pain is your body's way of telling you to rest. Working through pain can definitely make things worse. Sore muscles are different, but it sounds like the pain was caused by an impact of some sort. Rest for a couple days.

Comment: Sounds similar to something I have gone through(slammed my elbow on a table), anyway, it usually will go away after a couple days as long as you rest it. Otherwise, it probably isn't the same thing I have gone through before, I'm guessing.

Comment: I probably would rest it, failing to rest injuries can cause them to last a whole lot longer.